# redirect root url to index.html with nginx

Tags: redirect, caching, nginx

For a rails application that keeps on crashing for some redis issues that I am still trying to solve, I am trying to temporarly solve the problem with full page caching.

The page caching works fine, but for the root url, the cached page is not served without parameters.

http://www.example.com  goes straight to the app, but http://www.example.com/index.html serve the cached page

To avoid the ugly 500 errors, I would like to redirect requests to /index.html

I tried a few combinaisons, such as

```
location = / {
    rewrite / /index.html;
}
```

It worked for the root url, but blocked other urls such as /blog/, who then also was redirected to the root /index.html

I am not sure if I should resolve that with a redirect, or maybe is there something wrong with my caching parameters ?

here is my current nginx config:
https://pastebin.com/m9rj0Axt